# Visual force email template error

Tags: visualforce, email-template, related-list

Hi SalesForce Community.

I am hoping you can help,I have encountered different issues with my email template, and i have searched different forums and getting my self more and more confused.
To give some context I am trying to Create a VF email template that returns fields from the related list on the sales_and_marketing__c object.

I have three objects in question (See Two images attached)
sales_and_marketing__c, 
Material_Records__c, [image: Material Records]
Materials_Junction__c[image: Material Junction]

When on the sales_and_marketing__c object there is a related list.
When you scroll down to the related list and click on new it opens up a pop up box which is the Materials_Junction__c. [image: Related List On Sales MKT Object]

Materials_Junction__c object has three fields (see Material Junction photo)

When you click on the magnifying class on "Material record" fields you are presenting with the following.[image: Material Selection] this is the Material_Records__c object.

After selecting your materials you will return to this screen(See below) you add in a quantity amount and press save[image: adding quantity amount]

Once you push "save" the materials you have selected along with quantity will be presented on the  sales_marketing object (as seen below)[image: Final Outcome]

On my email template i should see.

Name of "Sales and Marketing" Record ( so example above it would be "Test")
Then 5 lines to show the products, item , quantity

Recap : Products and Item comes from the Material_Records__c object, and quantity  from the Materials_Junction__c object

This is my attempt at my VF Page

```
    <messaging:emailTemplate recipientType="Contact"
relatedToType="sales_and_marketing__c"
subject="Testing VF page: {!relatedTo.name}">

<messaging:htmlEmailBody >  
<html>
    <body>
    <STYLE type="text/css">
        TH {font-size: 11px; font-face: arial;background: #CCCCCC; border-width: 1;  text-align: center } 
        TD  {font-size: 11px; font-face: verdana } 
        TABLE {border: solid #CCCCCC; border-width: 1}
        TR {border: solid #CCCCCC; border-width: 1}
     </STYLE>
     <font face="arial" size="2"> 

<p>Dear {!recipient.name},</p>
<p>Below is a list of materials related to : {!relatedTo.name}.</p>

<table border="0" >
    <tr > 
        <th>Action</th><th>Case Number</th><th>Subject</th><th>Creator Email</th>
    </tr>
    <apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.Materials_Junction__r}">
        <tr>
            <td><a href="https://na1.salesforce.com/{!cx.Materials_Record__c}">View</a> |
            <a href="https://na1.salesforce.com/{!cx.Materials_Record__c}/e">Edit</a></td>
              <td>{!cx.Materials_Record__r.Product__c}</td>
        <td>{!cx.Materials_Record__r.Active__c}</td>
        <td>{!cx.Materials_Record__r.Item__c}</td>
            </tr>
    </apex:repeat>                 
</table>
<p />
     </font>
        </body>
    </html>
</messaging:htmlEmailBody> 

<messaging:plainTextEmailBody>

Dear {!recipient.name},

Below is a list of cases related to Account: {!relatedTo.name}

[ product ] - [ active ] - [ Itemss] 

<apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.Materials_Junction__r}">
[ {!cx.Materials_Record__r.Product__c} ] - [ {!cx.Materials_Record__r.Active__c} ] - [{!cx.Materials_Record__r.Item__c} ]  
</apex:repeat>

For more information login to http://www.salesforce.com
</messaging:plainTextEmailBody>    
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

One obvious mistake is that you're trying to iterate over a reference (lookup) field:

```
<apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.Material_Records__c}">
```

Which implies that `Material_Records__c` is actually the lookup field on `Materials_Junction__c` list. So, it is complaining about the Id field because the value returned to cx is an Id, and of course [some id].Id is not valid.

To 'repeat' over a list of records, you need to iterate over the relationship record, denoted by the `__r`

```
<apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.Relationship_Name_On_Child_Object__r}">
```

However, I think your relatedTo object needs to be `Sales__c` (or Sales & Marketing?) object and then you'd iterate as follows (though I can't be sure what you've named your lookup relationships).

```
<apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.Materials_Junction__r}">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="https://na1.salesforce.com/{!cx.Materials_Record__c}">View</a> |
        <a href="https://na1.salesforce.com/{!cx.Materials_Record__c}/e">Edit</a></td>
        <td>{!cx.Materials_Record__r.Product__c}</td>
        <td>{!cx.Materials_Record__r.Active__c}</td>
        <td>{!cx.Materials_Record__r.Item__c}</td>
    </tr>
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/58168)

Comment: You might want to phrase this differently so it does not look like a question itself.

Comment: @ Adrian & batter.cord I have rephrased the title and body of the question. Please let me know if the question isn't clear . -I appreciate your feedback

Comment: Point taken @battery.cord, edited

Comment: @phil - please see updated title, question images of objects and fields .

Comment: @Masond3 not sure i've understood your relationships properly, but hopefully you can see what I'm getting at in the latest edit. The fundamental problem was that you had `relatedTo.Material_Records__c` as your relationship, giving the String.id message

Comment: Hi Phil- that does make sense. Unfortunately I don't have access to my pc so unable to give your recommendations a ago. I will try this first time thing at work tomorrow morning :)

Comment: @PhilHawthorn i have updated my question along with better screen prints, Hopefully that will help with the relationships. I have tried different variations but i am still encountering issues

Comment: Ok, do  you get a different error message or just not displaying what you want?

Comment: @PhilHawthorn - i get the following error  Materials_Junction__r for SObject sales_and_marketing__c.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48334/discussion-between-masond3-and-phil-hawthorn).

Answer (score 0):

Would like to thank @PhilHawthorn for helping me through this. Phil established that the error i was getting was due to the `Materials_Junction__r` does not exist.

He then realized i named the related list name, `Materials`, thus making the relationship `Materials__r` not `Materials_Junction__r`.

```
<messaging:emailTemplate recipientType="Contact"
relatedToType="sales_and_marketing__c"
subject="Testing VF page: {!relatedTo.name}">

<messaging:htmlEmailBody >  
<html>
    <body>
    <STYLE type="text/css">
        TH {font-size: 11px; font-face: arial;background: #CCCCCC; border-width: 1;  text-align: center } 
        TD  {font-size: 11px; font-face: verdana } 
        TABLE {border: solid #CCCCCC; border-width: 1}
        TR {border: solid #CCCCCC; border-width: 1}
     </STYLE>
     <font face="arial" size="2"> 

<p>Dear {!recipient.name},</p>
<p>Below is a list of materials related to : {!relatedTo.name}.</p>

<table border="0" >
    <tr > 

       <th>Product</th><th>Item</th><th>Quantity</th>


    </tr>
    <apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.Materials__r}">
       [ {!cx.Material_Records__c} ] 

        <tr>
              <td>{!cx.Material_Records__r.Product__c}</td>
              <td>{!cx.Material_Records__r.Item__c}</td>
              <td>{!cx.Quantity__c}</td>
            </tr>
    </apex:repeat>                 
</table>
<p />
     </font>
        </body>
    </html>
</messaging:htmlEmailBody> 

<messaging:plainTextEmailBody >

Dear {!recipient.name},

Below is a list of cases related to Account: {!relatedTo.name}

[Product] - [Item] - [Quantity] 

<apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.Materials__r}">
[ {!cx.Quantity__c} ]   
</apex:repeat>

For more information login to http://www.salesforce.com
</messaging:plainTextEmailBody>    
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```